# How to install Conan package manager on openSUSE Tumbleweed the most correct way?

Tags: pip, opensuse, conan

I googled it around 1 hour and have found a lot of answers, but not for my exact situation, which I think is very frequent.

I need Conan for development and I use openSUSE.

Recommended installation of Conan is:

> To install Conan using pip, you need Python >= 3.5 distribution
> installed on your machine. Python 3.4 support has been dropped and
> Python 2 is being deprecated. Modern Python distros come with pip
> pre-installed.

But

1. various sources state to avoid pip and use zypper,
2. zypper does not have conan,
3. pip is not even installed on updated Tumbleweed,

..so should I install pip using `zypper install python3-pip` and then call `python3-pip install conan` or is there any more correct way of installing conan on openSUSE Tumbleweed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install using pip, it's recommendation from Conan and the best way for easier updated in the future.

There are more openSUSE users running Conan, and probably they are using pip too. I see no problem installing pip, it's multi-platform and well maintained. There is no Zypper package for Conan, and probably won't be in a near future, because itrequires demands and most important, maintenance. For now, there is no such community chorus asking for it.

If you don't want to install the current Python available for your system, but an alternative, I recommend you
[pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), which can be easily installed thought [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer). Even if you try to install from sources, in your case, you will need pip command for the installation.

For more information, please read the official installation section:

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html

https://conan.io/downloads.html

Comment: Actually I am happy with the Python provided, because it's the latest stable or something.

Comment: Great to know that openSUSE offers the latest version!